# Why Input box in angularjs is not editable?

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs

I have done a code which has an input box with angular's ng-model directive.

```
<div class="dragable inputVarBlock" id="manualInput">
       <input type="text" ng-model="manualInput" />    
</div>
```

This is the code in angular controller:

```
$scope.manualInput = 0;
```

Here I'm unable to edit the input box. Even I tried adding **'pointer-events:all'** in the div style, checking one of the stack overflow questions..

```
<div class="dragable inputVarBlock" id="manualInput" style="pointer-events:all;">
      <input type="text" ng-model="manualInput" />    
</div>
```

But nothing happened.

**EDIT :** When I remove the input box from that div it is working fine. But it must be in that div. I can't move this out of the div.

What must be the solution for this?

Comment: is there any css for dragable inputVarBlock class?

Comment: Remove class and then try

Comment: yes. There is a draggable class. And it is working after I remove the class. But that div must be a draggable one. After the div drag and drop I'm using using the input box value for some calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your code

```
$('.dragable inputVarBlock').click(function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

And you can use ngDraggable directive. Here is the link [check This Out](https://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/vLaWLX)